# Добавить поле в модель из select (select sum(weight) as weight from table)

Tags: laravel

Есть две таблицы:

```
Users: 
id,
name,
weight
```

и

```
Things:
id,
user_id,
weight
```

Модель `User` привязана отношением к другой модели.

Мне нужно, чтобы при любых обращениях к модели `Users` мне она возвращалась с полями:

```
id,
name,
weight,
full_weight
```

`full_weight` = `(select sum(weight) from things where user_id=users.id) full_weight` + `users.weight`

и сортировкой по полю `full_weight`

Answer (score 2):

Можно добавить в текущему перечню модели `User` поле, которые будет всегда автоматически возвращаться с другими стандартными полями при запросе. В модели:

```
protected $appends = ['full_weight'];

public function getFullWeightAttribute()
{
    //$this->things // получить коллекцию связанных вещей
    return 76; // перед этим любая ваша логика, запросы и всё, что душе угодно
}
```

Comment: вариант не плохой. Единственное - не сортирует в запросе, а нужно сортировать уже коллекцию

Comment: @SanyaH Если вы будете запрашивать коллекцию пользователей, то у вас будет огромное количество запросов. Самый простой вариант - в модели пользователей сделать поле full_weight и обновлять его при любых изменениях в модели Things. Т.е. не вычислять всё каждый раз, а делать это только тогда, когда есть изменения. Ну или использовать кэш.

Comment: Почему огромное? Сейчас три запроса: Model::with('users') - это два, плюс еще один на получения things с модели User через отношение